# I'm Building an auto dialer with Twilio.Device Js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twilio

I'm building an auto dialer with twilio and I'm a litle bit stuck . I succed with getting 2 outbound calls from my browser and when the first hangs up or busy the second one starts . but I want to implement it for many calls from an array of phones in my sql Db .

here is my code -  I'm starting with connecting to twilio and getting a token after that I'm making an array of phones using an AJAX call to my db with php code , Then I'm making a $GetJson request for the first phone and the next phone (if exist) from the Db and finally I'm starting a twilio.device.connect and when the first disconnect the second's starts:

status_progress.php

```
                /********TWILIO **********/
            $.getJSON('../../twilio/token.php').done(function (data) {
            console.log('Token: ' + data.token);
            console.log('Identity: ' + data.identity);

            // Setup Twilio.Device
            Twilio.Device.setup(data.token);

            Twilio.Device.ready(function (device) {
            console.log('Twilio.Device Ready!');

            });

            Twilio.Device.error(function (error) {
            console.log('Twilio.Device Error: ' + error.message);
            });

            Twilio.Device.connect(function (conn) {
            console.log('Successfully established call!');
            });

            Twilio.Device.disconnect(function (conn) {
            console.log('Call ended.');

            });




            Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn) {
            console.log('Incoming connection from ' + conn.parameters.From);
            var archEnemyPhoneNumber = '+12099517118';

            if (conn.parameters.From === archEnemyPhoneNumber) {
            conn.reject();
            console.log('It\'s your nemesis. Rejected call.');
            } else {
            // accept the incoming connection and start two-way audio
            conn.accept();
            }
            });



            //setClientNameUI(data.identity);
            })
            .fail(function () {
            console.log('Could not get a token from server!');
            });




            // Bind button to hangup call
            document.getElementById('closeCall').onclick = function () {
            console.log('Hanging up...');
            Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
            };

            $("#phoneThem").live("click", function() { 

            var arr = [];
            var i =0;
            $('.checkDeal:checked').each(function () {
            arr[i++] = $(this).val();

            });

            var arr_value = JSON.stringify(arr);
            var conected = 'no';

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'make_call_list.php',
            data: {arr_checked : arr_value}, // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function(calls)
            {

            $.getJSON('make_a_call.php').done(function (data) {

            var arr = data.arr;



            var params = {
            To: data.phone + '-' + data.crm

            };

            console.log('Calling ' + params.To + '...' );
            var connection = Twilio.Device.connect(params);



            connection.on('disconnect', function(conn) {
            console.log("the call has ended");
            var params2 = {
            To: data.phone_next + '-' + data.crm
            };


            console.log('Calling ' + params2.To + '...' );
            var connection_2 = Twilio.Device.connect(params2);

            });
            });





            }, // SUCCES MAKE A CALL LIST 

            });




            });
```

this is the twiml code :

```
<?php
 require_once 'twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php';
 use Twilio\TwiML\VoiceResponse;

 $break = $_POST['To'];


 $break_arr = explode('-',$break);

 $prefix = '+972';

 $response = new VoiceResponse();
 $dial = $response->dial('', ['callerId' => '+972 50-225-8234']);
 $break_arr[0] = ltrim($break_arr[0] , '0');
 $break_arr[0] = $prefix.$break_arr[0] ;
 $dial->number($break_arr[0], ['statusCallbackEvent' => 'initiated 
 ringing answered completed',
 'statusCallback' => 
 'https://crm.unic.co.il/crm_test_zone/handleDialCallStatus.php? 
  crm='.$break_arr[1].'',
  'statusCallbackMethod' => 'POST']);


  echo $response;

 ?>
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question - what is not working with all that code?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Rather than write out the code to sequentially dial all of the numbers, you can use the callback functions within the Twilio Device to trigger the next call to happen.

What I would do is load all of the numbers you want to dial into the front end in an array.

Then, I would create a function that takes two arguments; the current index of the number you are dialling and the array of numbers. The function would check to make sure the current index is still within the array and if it isn't return (all numbers have been dialled). Otherwise, it would generate a call to the number in the array. It would also set up a listener for the disconnection event for that call. When it disconnects, it calls the same function again, but moves the index on 1.

Finally, call that function with the initial index of 0 and the array of numbers. Something a bit like this:

```
const array = getArrayOfNumbers();

function dialNumber(index, array) {
  if (index > array.length) return; 

  const connection = Twilio.Device.connect({ number: array[index] });

  connection.on('disconnected', function() {
    dialNumber(index+1, array);
  });
}

dialNumber(0, array);
```

Let me know if that helps at all.